# Change Current Branch Programmatically

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to change the branch at runtime using code (AEF)? How can you do this at runtime? Say I have a custom Action that when clicked I want to change the company using code, how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to select or view data in another company this post should give you some ideas... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073983/save-data-to-different-company

Comment: As for branch I assume you can just sent the branchID value in the document if you are updating/inserting data. I have never tried to change the "current" default branch for the user so not much help here.

Comment: Can you please clarify, do you want to programmatically set the CompanyID or the BranchID? Can you also tell for what document (Sales Order, for instance) you need to explicitly set BranchID (or CompanyID)?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I mean the branch of the current session. Not changing the document's branch. Let's say that I am in a specific screen and I want to change the current Branch of the session programmatically. It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is code that can be implemented that will programmatically change the current branch.

```
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;

namespace AccessInfoChange
{
    public class BranchMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<BranchMaint>
    {
        public PXAction<BranchMaint.BranchBAccount> changeBranch;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Change Branch")]
        [PXButton]
        public virtual IEnumerable ChangeBranch(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
                int branchObj = 5; //BranchID of Branch you would like to switch to
                PXContext.SetBranchID(branchObj);
                HttpCookie branchCooky = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserBranch"];
                if (branchCooky == null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserBranch", "MAIN"));//BranchCD of Branch to switch
                else branchCooky.Value = branchObj.ToString();//String of IntegerID for BranchID to switch
            return adapter.Get();
        }
    }
}
```