# Acumatica set AccessInfo.branchID programmatically

Tags: acumatica

I want to set the AccessInfo.branchID prorammatically. Thanks[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BZsW.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Current Branch Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695603/change-current-branch-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for this!