# Creating Sale order using Acumatica Framework

Tags: acumatica

I have 2 companies and the requirement is to create a sales order in B company whenever a purchase order created in A company.

I have a working code to create a sales order using Acumatica framework and I am not sure to create a sales order in B company while logged into A company.

I prefer to do it using the framework instead of web services. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this via web services if you use PXLoginScope. There is a similar question here that should help...

[Save data to different company](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073983/save-data-to-different-company/42081623#42081623)

Sample:

```
using (var ls = new PXLoginScope("admin@OtherCompany"))
{
    //Sales order creation here for other company
}
```